# Performance testing a web app using Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm new to jmeter, i tried performance test a web app using it,

It has 4 pages,

```
Login page(Http Authorization Manager)
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
```

Here, when i use my app in real time it take too much time(> 2 sec) to load from one page to another.
But, in jmeter the results shows that the pages loads in quick time(avg time - 668 ms).

Is it hitting the pages individually?(i.e, from login page to page 1 and login page to page 2, etc)

What i wanted to know is, for the below scenario how my app performs with more samples.

Sequence : Login - goto page 1 - click on a link - goto page 2 - click on a link- goto page 3

Or Is there any way to record a sequence and do a load test with 100 users or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here, when i use my app in real time it take too much time(> 2 sec) to load from one page to another. But, in jmeter the results shows that the pages loads in quick time(avg time - 668 ms).

There are some reasons why JMeter is faster:

- Jmeter opens only html page, browser opens page with pictures and with another stuff
- Jmeter doesn't render html and JS, but browser does

Make some changes to your JMeter script:

- Add HTTP Cookie Manager
- Add HTTP Cache Manager
- Add HTTP Request Defaults
- Move Login page as child into Once Only Controller (as you won't login each time, right?)

Comment: The HTTP Request defaults been added already, but how HTTP Cookie/Cache Manager will help to resolve this issue? Does this related with the performance of the app? Please explain.

Comment: HTTP Cookie Manager - is for saving cookie sessions. Cache Manager is to simulate real user testing, as in real condition browser caches pages, but for your situation it's optional, you have only 4 pages.